Why are quotes not removed during expansion in zsh, as stated in the docs?
Consider the below snippet, which does a search with fdfind.
opts='--hidden --no-ignore --exclude ".git"'
fdfind ${=opts}

(note the equality sign, which turns on word splitting in zsh so it behaves like sh).
That snippet does not exclude .git from the search. Why is that?
Relevant parts of the docs (I added bold):

14 Expansion
Process Substitution Parameter Expansion Command Substitution
Arithmetic Expansion Brace Expansion
These five are performed in left-to-right fashion. On each argument,
any of the five steps that are needed are performed one after the
other. Hence, for example, all the parts of parameter expansion are
completed before command substitution is started. After these
expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters ‘\’,‘’’ and ‘"’
are removed.


6.9 Quoting
A character may be quoted (that is, made to stand for itself) by
preceding it with a ‘\’. ‘\’ followed by a newline is ignored.
A string enclosed between ‘$’’ and ‘’’ is processed the same way as
the string arguments of the print builtin, and the resulting string is
considered to be entirely quoted. A literal ‘’’ character can be
included in the string by using the ‘\’’ escape.
...
All characters enclosed between a pair of single quotes (’’) that is
not preceded by a ‘$’ are quoted. ...
Inside double quotes (""), parameter and command substitution occur, and ‘\’ quotes the characters ‘\’, ‘‘’, ‘"’, ‘$’, and the first
character of $histchars (default ‘!’).

Doing this the "zsh-way", with arrays instead of word-splitting a string, produces the desired outcome:
opts=(--hidden --no-ignore --exclude ".git")
fdfind $opts

As such, my question is not how to fix it, but rather why the first example above does not work as expected.
I suspect it is because the nested quotes are not removed after the parameter expansion, but that seems odd since the docs specifically states that quotes are removed after such expansion is done.

An aside - you don't need $=ary to expand an array, just $ary. An = expansion might give unexpected results; try: v=(a 'b c' d); printf '_%s_\n' $v ___ $=v.

Why do you think you need to put double quotes around .git?

@Barmar I don't, it's an example. It would have been useful if the string scalar was two words.


${=spec}
${==spec}
Perform word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during the evaluation of spec,  [..]

So word splitting is performed on the result of ${spec}. Word splitting does not remove quotes, the same way in POSIX sh, quotes would not be removed.

14 Expansion

These expansions are performed on what you type. When you type echo "*" then after all expansions " are removed. These are different set of expansion from what happens with the result of ${spec}.

6.9 Quoting

Yes, according to quotes section, when you type echo "*" then * part is quoted. It has nothing to do with what happens with the result of expansion of ${spec}. There is also no expansion that would remove quotes.

Maybe worth stressing that double quotes contained in a variable have no special meaning when performing word splitting. eg. if you had opts='"before after"', then echo $opts would expand to echo '"before' 'after"' and NOT echo '"before after"'. That is, it would expand into two arguments, not one.

Can you provide a documentation reference that would support the claim that these processing phases distinguish between characters that are there because they were on the original command line, and characters that are there because they were produced by previous processing phases? The docs just say "After these expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters ‘\’,‘’’ and ‘"’ are removed." They don't say "if those characters were present in the original command line".

hi @user2357112, no, I checked and I do not have more time.

Thank you, Kamil. Where in the docs does it state that the two expansion situations differ, as you say? I did not think there was a difference between shell script code evaluated directly on the command line, and code evaluated from inside scripts (assuming the same interpreter). As noted, the docs says: After these expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters ‘\’,‘’’ and ‘"’ are removed. In other words, parameter expansion happens, then quotes are removed. Perhaps I misunderstood the docs, and there is no further processing of the words substituted in after expansion.

... (continuation of above comment)... As noted, perhaps I misunderstood and in fact what happens is that whatever is substituted in after an expansion gets no further processing done to it. Meaning, if the quotes were not removed from the parameter higher up in the script, through prior expansion, then the quotes are kept after the parameter expansion. In other words, there is only "one passthrough" of expansion, it does not iterate multiple times. Is this described in the docs somewhere?

hi @Magnus I agree with you - this is what documentation states and you are understanding the docs correctly, this is what it says. (I even oddly think this is not the first time I have this discussion). The reality is, quotes coming from the result of expansions are not removed, i.e. echo $(echo '"') prints ". Zsh documentation is really only minimal. I do not know what to write. I'll remove the first part of my answer.

My gut feeling here is that the script is interpreted from top to bottom, and expansions only happens once. Meaning, if $FOO expands to $BAR, it does not again expand $BAR. I will mark the answer as accepted.
